# regular expression affected by everything around it preventing a match

Tags: regex

I have a simple regular expression for emails that I want to use, so it matches test@test.com for example, I don't care about what's around the email, except for one case when it starts with a * I don't want the email to match in that case only. The regex I have does this but prevents other matches, for example, test>test@test.com it should match test@test.com in this case, but it doesn't, I've done extensive research I can't seem to figure it out, it should ONLY NOT match if there is a * in front of the email, no other case, from what I understand my current regex should do that.

```
((^[^\*][a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]+\D)$)
```

should match what is bolded

- **test@test.com**
- **test@test.com.com**
- test>**test@test.com**<test

shouldn't match

- *test@test.com

Comment: You don't need to escape `*` inside `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to make sure the character before the email is not a `*` using negative lookbehinds:

```
(?<!\*)\b[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)+
```

Here are the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/yaIkMS/1)

---

For more restricted tests you may also try [`(?<![*.+-])\b(?![.+-])[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/0KE0na/1) which excludes

```
*abc.test@test.com
*abc-test@test.com
*abc+test@test.com
```

etc.